# Button menu that hides divs whose classes don't match the button clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm making a button menu that hides divs whose classes don't match that of the button that was clicked. Each button when clicked should only show the div with the same class. I'm really confused by how to do this with Javascript and I'm hoping somebody will be able to help me out?

Thanks in advance!

```js
function sortTab(tabClass) {
  
}
```

```css
.curtain {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button id="moon" onclick="sortTab(this.class)">moon</button>
<button id="earth" onclick="sortTab(this.class)">earth</button>
<button id="saturn" onclick="sortTab(this.class)">saturn</button>
<button id="mercury" onclick="sortTab(this.class)">mercury</button>
<button id="neptune" onclick="sortTab(this.class)">neptune</button>
<button id="sun" onclick="sortTab(this.class)">sun</button>
<button id="jupiter" onclick="sortTab(this.class)">jujpiter</button>

<div id="instafeed" class="gallery-wrap">
  <div class="moon earth curtain"></div>
  <div class="saturn curtain"></div>
  <div class="mercury sun curtain"></div>
  <div class="neptune curtain"></div>
  <div class="jupiter curtain"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't assign ID to more than one element. Pass the value to your function to achieve what you want.

```js
function sortTab(btnId) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (element.id === btnId) {
      element.className = 'box';
    } else {
      element.className = 'hidden box';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sortTab('test1')">test1</button>
<button onclick="sortTab('test2')">test2</button>
<button onclick="sortTab('test3')">test3</button>



<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box" id="test1">test1</div>
  <div class="box" id="test2">test2</div>
  <div class="box" id="test3">test3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, ids cannot be repeated, only classes. That being said, this should suit your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
       <head>    
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script>
               function sortTab(tabID) {
                  var hidevalue="div.gallery-wrap > div:not(."+tabID+")";   
                   $("div").show();  
                   $(hidevalue).hide();
                }
           </script>
           <style> 
               .curtain {
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                    background: black;
                    margin: 10px;
                    color: white;
                    float: left;
                }
           </style>
       </head>

       <body>

          <button id="moon" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">moon</button>
          <button id="earth" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">earth</button>
          <button id="saturn" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">saturn</button>
          <button id="mercury" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">mercury</button>
          <button id="neptune" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">neptune</button>
          <button id="sun" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">sun</button>
          <button id="jupiter" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">jupiter</button>



           <br>

           <div id="instafeed" class="gallery-wrap">
                <div class="moon earth curtain"></div>
                <div class="saturn curtain"></div>
                <div class="mercury sun curtain"></div>
                <div class="neptune curtain"></div>
                <div class="jupiter curtain"></div>
                <div class="moon sun curtain"></div>
                <div class="moon mercury curtain"></div>
           </div>

        </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Yes I relize this now and I have changed my code to use classes. Is there a way to do what I want by using classes?

Comment: Yes, just create an html file with the code I posted and it should do the job.

Comment: Thank you but your code hides the div with the same id, rather than filtering it out to be the only div shown. What if the divs have more than 1 class (please look at me updated code). Thanks!

Comment: Fixed the filtering. I've also updated the answer to be more similar to the edited problem. Try to hide the moon class, to see it work.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to show the items related to the buttons clicked, not hide them forever. The two examples above do this but I need to be able to do it when a div has multiple classes. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Could you please clarify? Currently I'm hiding all elements that don't have moon as one it's classes, (supposing you click on the moon button) and each div does have more than one class.  For example : <div class="mercury sun curtain"></div>.

Comment: When you click moon all divs should hide except for the ones with moon. But when you click sun for example the divs marked with that class will reappear. The buttons are a way of sorting or filtering the divs by class.

Comment: Ahhh, now I think I understand. The latest edit should do the trick.

Comment: Anazing yes thank you! Now to figure out how to do it in plain JS?

Comment: If you want to do it in plain JS, something along the lines of what robinbansalsolutions answered would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sortTab(tabID) {
//alert(tabID);
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById("div_"+tabID).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button id="test1" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">test1</button>
<button id="test2" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">test2</button>
<button id="test3" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">test3</button>
<button id="test4" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">test4</button>
<button id="test5" onclick="sortTab(this.id)">test5</button>

  
  
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box" id="div_test1">test1</div>
  <div class="box" id="div_test2">test2</div>
  <div class="box" id="div_test3">test3</div>
  <div class="box" id="div_test4">test4</div>
  <div class="box" id="div_test5">test5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use above code... Two elements can not have same id. That's why we have added the div_ to the div ids. And map them in the code.

Comment: Great thank you, what if the divs had more than one id?

Comment: I updated my code to use classes, is there a way to make this work?